# Iterator of iterator

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator

Given an iterator of iterators, return all of the elements from the iterators in order. Looking for code review, optimizations, and best practices. Verifying complexity to be \$O(n)\$, where \$n\$ is the total number of elements from all iterators.

```
public class IteratorOfIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{

    private final Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iteratorOfIterator;
    private Iterator<Integer> currentIterator;

    public IteratorOfIterator(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iterator)  {
        this.iteratorOfIterator = iterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (currentIterator == null || !currentIterator.hasNext()) {
            if (!iteratorOfIterator.hasNext()) return false;
            currentIterator = iteratorOfIterator.next();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("the stuff cannot be null.");
        }
        return currentIterator.next();
    }


    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The remove operation is not supported.");
    }
}


public class IteratorOfIteratorTest {

    @Test
    public void testIterator() {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 7, 8));
        List<Iterator<Integer>> combined = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(list1.iterator(), null, list2.iterator()));

        IteratorOfIterator ioi = new IteratorOfIterator(combined.iterator());
        int[] expected = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
        int[] actual = new int[8];
        int i = 0;
        while (ioi.hasNext()) {
             actual[i] = ioi.next();
             i++;
        }
        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Iterators.concat` from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat%28java.util.Iterator...%29)

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any reason to limit this to `Integer`s.  The solution can be trivially genericized.

`IteratorOfIterator` is a clumsy name.  By analogy with Python's [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), I suggest calling this class `ChainIterator<T>`.  You can rename the `iteratorOfIterator` private variable accordingly, too.

I suggest adding an alternate constructor that takes an `Iterable<Iterator<T>>`, for convenience.

The `hasNext()` method seems fine.  As for `next()`, the message in the `NoSuchElementException` that you throw seems a bit weird; I would just omit it.

With not much extra effort, you can add support for `remove()`.

```
public class ChainIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Iterator<Iterator<T>> chain;
    private Iterator<T> currentIterator;
    private Iterator<T> lastIterator;

    public ChainIterator(Iterable<Iterator<T>> iterable)  {
        this(iterable.iterator());
    }

    public ChainIterator(Iterator<Iterator<T>> iterator)  {
        this.chain = iterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (currentIterator == null || !currentIterator.hasNext()) {
            if (!chain.hasNext()) return false;
            currentIterator = chain.next();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
            this.lastIterator = null;         // to disallow remove()
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        this.lastIterator = currentIterator;  // to support remove()
        return currentIterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (this.lastIterator == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        this.lastIterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `ChainedIterator` to match the adjective + noun advice from your other answer.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using `this` when it's not necessary, especially inconsistently in the same method as in `next`, but +1 otherwise.

Comment: I like `IteratorOfIterator`.

Answer (score 5):

Reversing the logic a little bit on iterators can often make a big difference in the way the code reads, and it can remove code duplication.

One of the performance issues of iterators is that each time you call `next()`, you call `hasNext()` twice... consider a typical iterator use case:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next();
    ... do something with o.
}
```

Now, you call `hasNext()` in the loop, and, internally, the first thing `next()` does, is call `hasNext()` again.

If the `hasNext()` method is 'heavy', it can be quite expensive. This is especially true because, often, most of the same work is required yet again, to perform the `next()` (a third time!).

There is a trick to prevent this work duplication: Do the work once *in advance*, and remember the state.

```
public class IteratorOfIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{

    private final Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iteratorOfIterator;
    private Iterator<Integer> currentIterator = null;
    private Integer next = null;
    private boolean isvalid = false;

    public IteratorOfIterator(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iterator)  {
        this.iteratorOfIterator = iterator;
        // call advance from the constructor!!
        advance();
    }

    private void advance() {
        if (currentIterator != null && currentIterator.hasNext()) {
            isvalid = true;
            next = currentIterator.next();
            return;
        }
        currentIterator = null;
        while (currentIterator == null && iteratorOfIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentIterator = iteratorOfIterator.next();
            if (currentIterator != null && currentIterator.hasNext()) {
                next = currentIterator.next();
                isvalid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        next = null;
        isvalid = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return isvalid;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (isvalid) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("the stuff cannot be null.");
        }
        Integer val = next;
        advance();
        return val;
    }


    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The remove operation is not supported.");
    }
}
```

The above code:

- reduces the multiple `hasNext()` calls to a simple boolean check
- the advance method is called only once per item
- it handles null values in both the `iteratorOfIterators` and in the `currentIterator`

Answer (score 4):

Limiting to Integer type is really unnecessary. It's easy enough to generalize, you can simply change the signature to `public class IteratorOfIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>` and replace all occurrences of `Integer` with `E`, that's it.

The constructor is not ergonomic. You can see this in the unit test, you have to bend over backwards to create a test case: put iterators in a list and then get iterator from that. How about simply a varargs of `Iterators`:

```
public IteratorOfIterator(Iterator<E>... iterators)  {
    // ...
}
```

As [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl) pointed out, think from the perspective of typical use cases to catch this kind of problems, and refactor to avoid repeated calls to `hasNext()`.

Your implementation allows `null` iterators. I think null iterators indicate messy code. If you are working with legacy projects you might be forced to handle these. If that's the case, I think it's better to filter out the null values in the constructor.

As [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl) pointed out, in your `next` method you don't need to handle the case when there is no next element. Let the underlying iterator take care of it. The user is not supposed to call `next` anyway without checking `hasNext` first.

#### Suggested implementation

```
public class ChainIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private final Iterator<E>[] iterators;
    private int index = 0;

    public ChainIterator(Iterator<E>... iterators) {
        this.iterators = iterators;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (true) {
            if (iterators[index].hasNext()) {
                return true;
            }
            if (index == iterators.length - 1) {
                return false;
            }
            ++index;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return iterators[index].next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public class ChainIteratorTest {
    @Test
    public void testSingle() {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        ChainIterator<Integer> iter2x = new ChainIterator<>(list1.iterator());
        for (Integer item : list1) {
            assertTrue(iter2x.hasNext());
            assertEquals(item, iter2x.next());
        }
        assertFalse(iter2x.hasNext());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConcatWithManyEmpty() {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(4, 5);
        ChainIterator<Integer> iter2x = new ChainIterator<>(
                Collections.<Integer>emptyList().iterator(),
                list1.iterator(),
                Collections.<Integer>emptyList().iterator(),
                Collections.<Integer>emptyList().iterator(),
                list2.iterator());
        for (Integer item : list1) {
            assertTrue(iter2x.hasNext());
            assertEquals(item, iter2x.next());
        }
        for (Integer item : list2) {
            assertTrue(iter2x.hasNext());
            assertEquals(item, iter2x.next());
        }
        assertFalse(iter2x.hasNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't store the iterators in an array (yet do accept them in such format!), you can easily use a `List<Iterator<E>>` by using `Arrays.asList` at the expensive of only one wrapper object.

Comment: You forgot to mention why do that. The current code doesn't need it. There's just no point, is there? If the code evolves in such a way that a `List` will make more sense, I can easily change it.

Comment: A fair point there, it might be just that I dislike working with arrays, but you are totally correct here.

Comment: I dislike working with arrays, too, but like the varargs syntax. It's a shame it uses arrays and not lists.

Comment: @IngoBürk I don't "like" arrays, but I very rarely use them. In most practical situations I need the power of lists. I dislike unnecessary things, and this array does everything I need, so why not.